# How to prevent &amp;#41; from being inserted in a Database in PHP?

Tags: php

I am working on a PHP/MySQL script that is inserting data into a database like this...

```
Caesar &amp;#40;courtesy post&amp;#41;
```

I know this is a basic question but how can I prevent the special characters from doing that?

Comment: maybe with urldecode() or str_replace()   ?

Comment: html_entity_decode() and urldecode() should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're not just HTML-escaping your content once, but actually doing it twice. The first thing you should do is try to find out *why* your content ends up that way, instead of attempting to decode it to an unescaped format. You should always escape for the format you're going to use the data in, escape with the SQL escape functions when inserting, and escape with htmlspecialchars (or a similar function) when presenting the data in HTML (and take note of the character encoding used).

If the data comes in this format from another source, use `html_entity_decode` to normalize the text again. That does however seem weird.

Comment: Yeah I just started a project on a clients existing codebase and noticed this problem, I am going to re-write it all and use PDO, hoping I won't have this problem then

Comment: I found out the data is coming in like this from the API I am getting it from